# How to convert protocol from http to https for web logic server

Tags: http, https, weblogic, protocols, environment

I am using weblogic server and deployed an application ear. My url is present
    `http://sbchydc:7006/console, Is there any way to change it to 
    https://sbchydc:7006/console or 
    https://sbchydc:7002/console(default SSL port)`. Any port is fine, just want to know how we can convert from http to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not pointed the version of your WebLogic Server. I am adding the solution for WebLogic 10.3, but it should also work in other versions.

In your WebLogic Server Administration Console, go to `Environment/Servers/[Your Managed or Admin Server] (wherever your ear is deployed)/Configuration/General` and enable `Enable SSL Listen Port`, configuring whichever port makes more sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Am working with weblogic 11g, Your suggestion is fine, while searching answers I came to know that I have to craete certs(keystore and truststore), and am not sure why they are used.
Plz let me help with these things, how to create, what's their use and how to configure them in weblogic.
If i change my url to 'https' and if i wont configure these certs , am i going to get an exception??.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about it, but the need for creating and configuring a SSL certificate is to sign your responses. There is no point in communicating over HTTPS without a SSL certificate. You won't get no exception, but your clients might.